# flatMap on Optional type complaining about unwrapping inside closure

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I can call `flatMap` on an Optional as expected if it's at the top level:

```
func id<T>(v: T) -> T {
    return v
}


var foo: Int?
foo.flatMap(id) // returns nil

foo = 1
foo.flatMap(id) // returns 1
```

However, when I try to use `flatMap` for what I can only imagine its intense purpose (composing multiple Optionals, in this case), the compiler throws an error:

```
var bar: Int?
foo.flatMap { $0 + bar.flatMap(id) }
// error: value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
// foo.flatMap { $0 + bar.flatMap(id) }
//                        ^
```

Why do I need to unwrap the optional inside the closure when I didn't in the first two examples? Doesn't that somewhat defeat the purpose of `flatMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reason

You can't add an optional and a number

```
var v1 : Int?

let sum = v1 + 2 //Will throw a compilation error
```

It is a compilation error because `v1` could be nil. It doesn't make sense to add 2 to `nil`

In your example `foo.flatMap { $0 + bar.flatMap(id) }`

`bar.flatMap(id)` returns an optional

## Solution

`foo.flatMap { $0 + (bar.flatMap(id) ?? 0)}`

Comment: Of course it does. I feel kind of dumb for not noticing this. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't even know `map` and `flatMap` existed on optionals till you had asked. so thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be under the impression that `flatMap` returns an unwrapped value. It doesn't. Yes, it does try to unwrap the original value, calling closure if this unwrapping succeeded (and returning whatever the closure returned), but returns `nil` if the original value could not be unwrapped. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) says, it:

> Evaluates the given closure when this `Optional` instance is not `nil`, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.
>
> ...
>
> **Returns:** The result of the given closure. If this instance is `nil`, returns `nil`.

As you can see, the result of `flatMap` is therefore an optional, e.g. if you look at the `flatMap` declaration:

```
 func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
```

So, let's go back and look at your first code snippet. You say:

> ```
> var foo: Int?
> foo = 1
> foo.flatMap(id) // returns 1
> ```

No. It returns a `Int?`, namely `Optional(1)` in this example. It does not return `1`.

So then consider:

```
var bar: Int?
let result = foo.flatMap { $0 + bar.flatMap(id) }
```

Since `bar.flatMap(id)` will return an `Int?`, the compiler is complaining that you're trying to add `$0` (the unwrapped value of `foo`, assuming it could unwrap it) with an `Optional<Int>`, resulting in the error because it asking whether you meant to unwrap the value from the latter half of this expression.

---

Just to make it clear, consider this example:

```
let result = foo.flatMap { value -> Int? in
    // calculate some result using `value`, which is `foo` unwrapped,
    // and return it; if `foo` couldn't be unwrapped, this closure is
    // not called and `result` is `nil`

    return calculatedValue
}
```

That is a nice functional equivalent to the following:

```
let result: Int?

if let value = foo {
    // calculate result from `value`, which is `foo` unwrapped
    // and update `result` accordingly

    result = calculatedValue
} else {
    // otherwise just set `result` to `nil`

    result = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `map()`, `flatMap()` does strip out optionality, but its primary purpose is for "flattening" a multidimensional array.

It maps items in one array into another array using the closure, then joins the results. Both optionals and arrays are "containers" and `flatMap()` removes one level of containment.

In your example, you are trying to add one unwrapped optional to an optional, which doesn’t work.

If you want to sum an array of optional integers, you could try this example.

```
let foo: Int?
let bar: Int?

let myArray = [foo, bar]

let sum = myArray.flatMap().reduce(0, +)
```

This will return the total of the integers, or zero if they are all nil.

Comment: FWIW, there are two notions of "flattening" arrays. One is flattening an array of arrays, e.g. `let foo = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]`. Then `let bar = foo.flatMap { $0 }` will return `[1,2,3,4,5]`. The second is compacting an array, removing optionals, e.g. as in the example you provide above. It's worth noting that effective Xcode 9.3, this latter use of `flatMap` has been renamed, and is now called `compactMap`, whereas the former use is still called `flatMap`.

Comment: But I agree with you, that using `flatMap` (and with Xcode 9.3, `compactMap`) with arrays, is a far more common use of these methods. You don't see people using `flatMap` with a single optional very often (though you can). +1

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I was not aware of compactMap. I just checked the Apple documentation and am I right to say that it only returns the String type?

Comment: No, if you don't specify the closure's return type and you have a complicated expression, sometimes the compiler gets confused and assumes you're returning `String?` types. But we use `flatMap` (and `compactMap`) with all sorts of return types. If you see the compiler seem to incorrectly infer that it's returning a `String?` for some reason, just explicitly define the closure's return type to remove ambiguity, and it will work fine. As you can see, it's a generic, so you can return whatever you want, but you just need to specify it sometimes to remove ambiguity for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.flatMap(id)` does not return 1. It returns `Optional(1)`.

`foo.flatMap { $0 + bar.flatMap(id) }` breaks because `foo.flatMap` can be unwrapped so it executes the closure. But `bar.flatMap(id)` cannot be evaluted to a non-optional (see my first point).

`flatMap`, in this context, does the same as this code:

```
var optionalInt = Int("5A")

if let unwrappedInt = optionalInt {
    optionalInt = unwrappedInt + 5
}
```

Notice how we have to use `if let` to unwrap to use the `+` operator?

One use of `flatMap` is it gives us the convenience of not having to unwrap to use `+`. If the expression evals to `nil` it doesn't execute. But the whole thing returns an optional. Like this:

`let result = optionalInt.flatMap { 5 + $0 }`

Here `result` evaluates to `nil`